# sqlalchemy rolling back data from bulk insert statement

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, insert, bulkinsert

I have a script with the purpose of taking in CSVs and bulk inserting that data in an sql table.

I am able to create a connection with my server and use a query to insert the data in, but as soon as the connection closes the session is rolled back and all the data gets deleted from my table.

After some research I've done I think it has to do with creating a session and commit the changes before closing my connection but I still cannot get it right and would appreciate some help.

Here is my current code so far:

```
     #Creat SQL connection using sql alchemy
        sql_engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
                'mssql+pyodbc://server_name/table_name?driver=SQL Server&Trusted_Connection=yes'
                                              ).connect()
     #Create a new session???
        Session = sessionmaker(bind=sql_engine)
        session = Session()
    
     #Iterate through csvs and bulk insert data
        cd = os.getcwd()
        all_files = glob.glob(cd + "/*.csv")
        for file in all_files:
            qry = "BULK INSERT [database_name].[schema].[table_name] FROM '" + file + "' WITH (FIRSTROW = 2, FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')"
            print(qry)
            a = sql_engine.execute(qry)
    
     #Commit changes and close connection??? (This is where the rollback happens)
        session.commit()
        sql_engine.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your `sql_engine` is not an `Engine` but a `Connection` since you create it with the `Engine.connect()` method, drop the `.connect()` at the end to actually create an `Engine`.

Then, you use this `sql_engine` connection to create `session`, but don't use the `session` to do your bulk insert, so you don't need the `session`.

Finally you commit the `session`, but not the `sql_engine`, and close the `sql_engine` connection, which means the data you've added via `sql_engine` is rolled back.

Using the Engine and a Connection to insert data are topics covered in the [SQLAlchemy tutorial`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/index.html).

---

Refactor of the code above (**untested**):

```py
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    'mssql+pyodbc://server_name/table_name?driver=SQL Server&Trusted_Connection=yes'
)

with engine.connect() as con:
    cd = os.getcwd()
    all_files = glob.glob(cd + "/*.csv")
    for file in all_files:
        qry = (
            "BULK INSERT [database_name].[schema].[table_name] "
            "FROM :filename "
            "WITH (FIRSTROW = 2, FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')"
        )
        con.execute(qry, {"filename": file})
    con.commit()
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time in this!
I still get one error when trying to commit though:
AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'commit'

Comment: Don't we need to commit using a session rather than a connection?

Comment: If you used a session, you would need to commit commit that session, but you execute your SQL with a connection, so you commit the connection. Your code only uses CORE SQLAlchemy, no ORM which is where the session is used.

Comment: See my refactor of your code, but you definitely commit on the connection. https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/data_insert.html#executing-the-statement